# Grouping points by attributes from field with possibly many values

Tags: qgis-3, point, atlas, virtual-layer

I have a shapefile "cities" with one unique `city_id` for each city (geometry polygon, although not relevant here) :

```
city_name ; city_id
New-York  ; 0001
Paris     ; 0002
London    ; 0003
```

And a shapefile "points" (geometry single point), each with a unique `point_id`, and a field `possible_city` containing a string of at least one or more `city_id` (if more than one, they are separated by "-") :

```
point_id ; possible_city
p1       ; 0001
p2       ; 0002
p3       ; 0001-0002-0003
p4       ; 0001-0003
```

I am aware this is a terrible method for simulating a 1-n link compared to a true database system; however I am stuck with these shapefiles.

I would like to create an atlas for each `city_id`, with every point mentioning that `city_id` in the `possible_city` field. For that I need to create a coverage layer with one feature for every `city_id` (polygon or multipoints does not matter for me).

Following [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/287527/qgis-3-2-atlas-with-set-of-points) I tried creating a virtual layer. However I seem to be unable to link the `cities.city_id` and `points.possible_city` fields. Here is what I tried :

```
SELECT st_union(p.geometry) as geometry, c.city_id
FROM points p, cities c
WHERE '%'||p.possible_city||'%' LIKE c.city_id
GROUP BY c.city_id ;
```

I wonder if I should use a `JOIN` and/or a `WHERE` clause here. I feel [this other question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297568/atlas-map-generation-in-qgis-using-point-layer-only?rq=1) may be useful too, however my problem seems to lie in the fact that I am trying to link two shapefiles with two fields in this weird, non-database-approved way.

Feel free to edit the question of the post for added clarity.

Comment: What is the output for your query? What is the output if you use `WHERE p.possible_city LIKE '%' ||c.city_id||'%'` instead?